# JAVA.net.SocketException when accessing API request in jenkins

Tags: java, rest, maven, jenkins, automation

I am testing an API request using RESTAPI Automation framework, selenium, and java. So while requesting the API I am getting **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** error on Jenkins. but on the local machine, it's working fine. I am not able to find any concrete solution.
[Error screenshot of jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/110tL.png)

Comment: Then you have a networking problem.  You used the wrong IP address, it's firewalled, there's no server running, or something like that.  Maybe the problem is in your code, maybe it's not.  You;d have to post some code to get an opinion on that part.

Comment: There is no problem with the code because it's working properly on the local machine. The other requests with the same endpoint are working fine but for some specific requests, it's throwing this exception.

Comment: *There is no problem with the code because it's working properly on the local machine.* And yet it does not work elsewhere.  That is, the code is only known to work some of the time.  You cannot thus conclude "no problem with the code".